# Sum column values in a table based on row values of a different table

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I want to sum column values in a table **DT2** based on row values of a different table **DT1** and store it in **DT3**

```
library(data.table)
DT1 <- data.table(x = seq(1,100, by = 1), 
                 y = round(runif(100,50, 60)),
                 z = round(runif(100, 61, 70)))

DT2 <- data.table(a = seq(1, 1000, by = 1),
                 b = round(rnorm(1000, 10,1)),
                 c = round(rnorm(1000, 20,1)),
                 d = round(rnorm(1000, 30,1)))
```

Initialize DT3

```
DT3 <- DT1[,.(x)]
DT3[,':='(e = 0,
          f = 0,
          g = 0)]
```

Using **for** loop for summing values

```
for(i in 1:nrow(DT1)){
  DT3[i, 2:4] <- DT2[DT1[i,y]:DT1[i,z], 
                     lapply(.SD, sum),
                     .SDcols = c("b", "c", "d")]
}
```

This works fine. The only issue is it takes lot of time 
as the number of rows and columns increases in **DT1** and **DT2**. I have  **DT1** with more than 100000 rows. This takes me around 30 mins. Is there a faster way to do this operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
library(data.table)
DT1 <- data.table(x = seq(1,100, by = 1), 
                 y = round(runif(100,50, 60)),
                 z = round(runif(100, 61, 70)))

DT2 <- data.table(a = seq(1, 1000, by = 1),
                 b = round(rnorm(1000, 10,1)),
                 c = round(rnorm(1000, 20,1)),
                 d = round(rnorm(1000, 30,1)))

matrix(DT1[, colSums(DT2[, -"a"][as.numeric(y:z)]), 1:nrow(DT1)]$V1,
       ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)

  #      [,1] [,2] [,3]
  # [1,]  114  223  324
  # [2,]   73  141  208
  # [3,]  112  222  323
  # [4,]  151  301  443
  # [5,]  133  263  382
  # ...
```

Iterate over `DT1` rows and extract vector `y:z` (`as.numeric(y:z)`). Pass this vector to `DT2` and get `colSums`.

Comment: This approach reduces the time by at least 1/3. Thanks.

Comment: @Madhu Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

In terms of single iterations, your code is already efficient. You are using `data.table` instead of `dataframe`, and the `lapply` statement is efficient as well.

Thus, I believe the major optimization should be focused on how you apply that sum statement.

**1. Avoid duplicate calculations:**

Check the results of `table(duplicated(DT1[,c("y", "z")]))` on your data. For the dummy data case, 30% of the summing operations are repeated. If you your data has such high duplication ratio, I would suggest calculating the results of the unique `y & z` first, then assigning the results to the main datatable afterwards.
.

**2. Parallelize your loop:**
Your iterations are independent, which makes the loop parallizable. Check the `foreach` package. Be careful with the `.combine` parameter / function though, as this might tremendously reduce the result combination overheads.